# Generate only level 2 menu

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to generate only the second level of the main menu. This is used on a different position on the subpage. I'm using the typoscript shown below. Only at the special value I need to have the current pageId, so it generates only the submenu of the active page. How can I get the current page id and add it to the special value below?

```
  submenu = HMENU
  submenu.wrap = <ul class="submenu">|</ul>
  submenu.special = directory
  submenu.special.value = {TSFE:id}

  submenu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      expAll = 1
      NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="sub-but">|</li>

      ACT = 1
      ACT.wrapItemAndSub =  <li class="active sub-but">|</li>            
    }    
  }
```

Comment: Try to add `submenu.special.value.insertData = 1`

Comment: I have added the line behind the special.value line, but without succes. No menu is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `submenu.special.data = TSFE:id` instead of `submenu.special.value = {TSFE:id}`.

This code is verified to work.

```
submenu = HMENU
submenu.wrap = <ul class="submenu">|</ul>
submenu.special = directory
submenu.special.data = TSFE:id

submenu {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    expAll = 1
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="sub-but">|</li>

    ACT = 1
    ACT.wrapItemAndSub =  <li class="active sub-but">|</li>            
  }    
}
```

Comment: I have added exacte the code line with special.data = TSFE:id but no menu is generated.

Comment: I update the answer with the fully working example. If this does not work for you, then your problem is the assignment to the template and not the menu generation.